# Apache FOP image not hide

Tags: image, overflow, hidden, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I set `margin-right:1.0in`.
The last column show the image but hide the text. I know the last column is overflow, but why the the image is showing but the text not?
How to hide all of the content include the image?

[image: generated PDF]

The file content is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-height="8.5in" page-width="14.0in" margin-left="0.1in" margin-right="1.0in" margin-bottom="0.2in" margin-top="0.2in" master-name="all-pages">
            <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-bottom="0.1in" margin-top="0.1in"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="0.1in" region-name="xsl-region-header"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0.1in" region-name="xsl-region-footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="reportSeqn1PageMasterParametersSet">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages"/>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="reportSeqn1PageMasterColumnSet1">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages"/>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="reportSeqn1PageMasterColumnSet2">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages"/>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="reportSeqn1PageMasterImageSet">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages"/>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force" master-reference="reportSeqn1PageMasterColumnSet1" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-header">
            <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" text-align="end">Dec 07, 2016</fo:block>
            <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" text-align="end">05:55 PM</fo:block>
            <fo:block font-weight="normal" font-family="Arial" font-size="12pt" text-align="center" text-decoration="none">Finance Integration Tasks</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-footer">
            <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" text-align="end">
                                                                Page <fo:page-number/>  Column set 1 of 2</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block-container width="1653.2640000000001pt">
                <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" margin-top="5pt">
                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="1653.2640000000001pt">
                        <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="4" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="5" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="6" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="7" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="8" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="9" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="10" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="11" column-width="84.43636363636364pt"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="12" column-width="724.464pt"/>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)"># of Critical Issues</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Description</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)"># of Other Issues</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test1</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test2</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test3</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test4</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test5</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test6</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(51,102,153)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Test7</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(255,255,255)" border-top-color="rgb(255,255,255)" border-right-color="rgb(255,255,255)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)">title</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="#ffff00">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="Black"  text-align="left">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" color="Black" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none">Tin
Can</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="Red"  text-align="left" font-weight="bold">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" color="Red" font-weight="bold" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none">ABCD</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="Black"  text-align="center">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" color="Black" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none">4</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="Black"  text-align="right">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" color="Black" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none">19</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="Black"  text-align="left">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" color="Black" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none">Tin
Can</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000"  text-align="left">ABCD</fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000"  text-align="left">Tin Can</fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000"  text-align="left">ABCD</fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000"  text-align="left">Tin Can</fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000"  text-align="left">ABCD</fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-top-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-right-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="Black"  text-align="right">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" color="Black" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none">Tin 
Can</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(255,255,255)" border-top-color="rgb(255,255,255)" border-right-color="rgb(255,255,255)" border-left-color="rgb(200,215,227)" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                                    <fo:block-container >
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="rgb(255,255,255)"  text-align="left">
                                            <fo:inline xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal">ABCD</fo:inline> <fo:external-graphic src="url('file:///C:/Users/sujianrong/Desktop/fop-2.1-bin.tar/fop-2.1-bin/fop-2.1/examples/fo/graphics/fop.jpg')" content-width="10pt" /> </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block id="reportSeqn1last-pageColumnSet2"/>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow="hidden"` to the `fo:region-body`.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#overflow